# Why does the forge event not fire?

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to see if someone joined a world and then print something to console but the event doesn't seem to fire. Can someone help me? Here is my code:

```
package pl00py_TR.pl00pyspvpmod;

import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.living.LivingSpawnEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPostInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.event.FMLPreInitializationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;

@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.MOD_NAME, version = Reference.VERSION)
public class Pl00pysPVPMod {

    @EventHandler
    public void preInit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event) {

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void postInit(FMLPostInitializationEvent event) {
        System.out.println("DIRT BLOCK >> " + Blocks.dirt.getUnlocalizedName());
    }

    public class EventTest {
        @SubscribeEvent
        public void OnEvent(LivingSpawnEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Event Test");
            if (event.entity instanceof EntityPlayer) {
                System.out.println("Player Joined");
            }
        }
    }

    public void RegisterEvents() {
        System.out.println("Registering Events...");
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(EventTest.class);
    }
}
```

The code is for 1.8.9 and I am trying to find out if someone joins a server/world. I am trying to get the players coords and print them to console but the event doesn't fire or initialize. Could someone explain why this is happening and give me an idea of how to fix this?

Comment: What do you expect will call `RegisterEvents`?

Answer (score 0):

Could be wrong but try `MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new EventTest());` instead of `MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(EventTest.class);`

In the documentation for `EventBus`

> `void register(java.lang.Object target)`

Answer (score 0):

i know i'm far to late but you can either use `register(new EventClass())`
which allows the event method to not be static or make the method static and use `register(EventClass.class)`